# API Gateway, error on enabling CORS: The Empty Model does not exist

Tags: amazon-web-services, cors, aws-api-gateway

I just built my first API Gateway API. Testing a route by pasting it directly into the address field of my browser, works fine. However, using the same route in a fetch from React, gets an error in the browser console:

> Access to fetch at
> 'https://5as8tposvh.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/Prod/https://5as8tposvh.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/Prod/blast-jobs'
> from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
> mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

So reading up a little, I discover that I need to enable CORS in API Gateway's console on AWS. (Why wasn't this an issue from the browser's address bar?) So I go to do that as recommended [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors-console.html). But there's an option not described in the documentation:

> default gateway response [ ] 4xx  or [ ] 5xx.

It isn't self-explanatory and I have no idea when that default response might take place. So I leave both boxes unchecked. I wonder, does that contribute to what comes next? Here's the outcome:
[image]
and furthermore, from this point, I can't even get back to the Enable CORS page, to try different options! Is there a way?

Clicking on one of those little exclamation marks gets "Invalid response status code specified". Is this related to the empty model issue? Is it related to not checking one of those boxes on the previous page? And where to go to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

> Why wasn't this an issue from the browser's address bar?

Because that's exactly what CORS does.

If your API gets requests from another domain, you have to tell the browser you've opted in to serving these requests.

If you are going to host your front-end JS code and API code on different domains (like you're doing now), you'll really have to read up on what CORS is doing.

What you're doing now (enabling CORS for all domains) might be a major security flaw.

> default gateway response [ ] 4xx or [ ] 5xx.

API Gateway returns some default responses if your request cannot reach the integration at all. This can happen if there's an authentication failure, validation failure, malformed template or something like this.

When it happens, it will return what AWS calls a [default gateway response](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-gatewayResponse-definition.html).

It's subject to CORS as well. If you want your JS code to be able to process these errors (i.e. see their HTTP codes, error texts and so on), you'll need to enable CORS for these responses too.

> Is this related to the empty model issue?

The "Enable CORS" button is a console feature. When you click it, it will do a series of changes to your gateway. It's handled in the browser's code.

One of these changes is creating the `OPTIONS` method with a mock integration for your endpoint with the `Empty` model for the response body. It has to exist.

When you create a new API Gateway, by default, two models are created: `Empty` and `Error`. However, you could have deleted them after they had been created, or overwritten when you imported an OpenAPI definition. Old API Gateways (created prior to early 2020 or so) didn't have those models either.

So what's happening is that the console is trying to create a method with a model attached to it, but can't find the model.

I'm not sure how to fix console errors like this, but you can try to switch to the new console (there's a link at the bottom of the left hand side pane).

To create the model if it's missing:

1. Go to Gateway / Models
2. Create a new model with name `Empty` and content type `application/json`
3. Paste this schema:

   ```json
   {
     "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
     "title" : "Empty Schema",
     "type" : "object"
   }
   ```